# PHP PDO and JavaScript Fetch() Code And JSON Works, But I Can't Work Out The How The JSON Aspect Is Working

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch-api

I have some PHP and JavaScript that works by PHP updating a MySQL database, and then outputting the updated code onto the page without a hard refersh using the JavaScript `fetch()` method. This code works, and although I understand the fundamentals (and the vast majority) of the code below, there is a part of if it I can't quite get my head around.

a) In this PHP snippet (full code further down) the database is queried and then set as the JSON data type:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$board_row['board_name'];
echo json_encode($board_row);
exit;
```

It only seems to output `$board_row['board_name']` but in the JavaScript code (also shown futher down) both the `json.board_name` and `json.board_id` are used to output data onto the page, not just the value from the `$board_row['board_name']` value?

b) In the line `echo json_encode($board_row);` where is this actually echoed? I've only ever used `echo` to directly output data into a specific HTML element in the past. Is this just echoed in the headers so the JSON can then be accessed in the JavaScript code?

c) When outputting database values in PHP I always wrap them in `htmlspecialchars()`, the JSON code in this example doesn't seem to be going through an equivalent process for security reasons?

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-board-name'])) {

    $create_board_name = $_POST['create-board-name'];
    
    try {
        // insert into database
        $createBoardSQL = "
            INSERT INTO boards (board_name, user_id) 
            VALUES (:board_name, :user_id )
        ";
    
        $bstmt = $connection->prepare($createBoardSQL);
        $bstmt->execute([
            ':board_name' => $create_board_name,
            ':user_id' => $db_id
        ]);

        // ----- fetch as JSON
        if(isset($_POST['json_response'])) {
            $board_stmt = $connection->prepare("
                SELECT * FROM `boards` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id 
                AND `board_name` = :board_name 
                ORDER BY `board_id` DESC");

            $board_stmt -> execute([
                ':user_id' => $db_id,
                ':board_name' => $create_board_name
            ]); 

            $board_row = $board_stmt->fetch();

            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $board_row['board_name'];
            echo json_encode($board_row);
            exit;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
let boardModuleForm = document.querySelector('.board-module-form');

// URL details
let myURL = new URL(window.location.href),
pagePath = myURL.pathname;

if (boardModuleForm) {
    boardModuleForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.submitter && e.submitter.classList.contains('js-fetch-button')) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData(this);

            formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
            formData.set('json_response', 'yes');

            fetch (pagePath, {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(function(response) {

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    response.json().then(function(json){
                        
                        const newBoardName = json.board_name,
                        boardId = json.board_id;
                            
                        const newButton = `
                        <button name="board-name" type="submit">
                            <span>${newBoardName}</span>
                            <span style="margin:0" class="add-icon flex">+</span>
                        </button>
                        <input class="board-id-value" type="hidden" value="${boardId}">
                        `
                        // add new button from above onto page
                        document.querySelector('.board-list').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newButton);
                    
                    });

                }

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            })

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: `$board_row['board_name'];` Does nothing

Comment: The `$board_stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM \`boards\` WHERE \`user_id\` = :user_id AND \`board_name\` = :board_name ORDER BY \`board_id\` DESC");` is a complete waste of time on a couple of levels, as it looks like there are only 2 columns, at least there will only be 2 columns set in the Previous `INSERT` and you already know what those 2 values will be, ___So why do the select at all___. And why sort 1 row?

Comment: `echo json_encode($board_row);` So `$board_row` contains the 2 columns you INSERTED before the select and SELECTED using `*`

Comment: You could remove the whole `// ----- fetch as JSON` sections and replace with `echo json_encode( ['board_name'=>$create_board_name,'board_id'=>$db_id] );`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - thanks for the pointers. Am I correct that because `json_encode()` outputs string values, thus any script tags are always outputted as strings and not DOM elements? This seems to be the case when outputted, but because the `<` tags etc aren't changed to their entity e.g. `&#60;` it makes me nervous. I'm relatively new to this and very new to JSON.

Comment: Yes, json_encode creates a string, you wouldn't be able to acho an associative array.Why don't you use element.innerText = $yourData so you don't have to worry about escaping the HTML?